# Trouble uploading photos with iPhone app - app said to lodge issue here

Tags: bug

The app is having trouble uploading photos to an answer and told me to raise an issue here. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is anything that we, the moderators of HSM, could do to help you solve this technical issue. I'm guessing that the app actually told you to go to *Meta Stack Exchange* (and not the HSM Meta site) which, confusingly, is its own *main* Stack Exchange site. I believe that the correct place to report bugs is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229966/where-to-report-app-bugs).